# Blazor Server Side authentication - Authorization works without auth middleware being used

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to clarify a few questions I have on SSB authentication and authorization. From what I know - blazor does not run within the .Net core pipeline context. Initially when the app is started, all the normal context pipeline rules apply but once the blazor app itself starts, it runs off the signalR connection to the client.

I'm using azure AD to authenticate users to the blazor app. Based on MS docs, below is the default project created when you enable Microsoft Identify Platform as the auth provider in a server side blazor app:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.MapControllers();
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

    app.Run();
}
```

Most of it makes sense to me as its similar to default MVC authentication. AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp sets up the auth mechanism to OIDC, AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI() is setup for the actual login/logout methods.

**Below are things I don't understand:**

Why is **AddControllersWithViews()** needed when **AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()** can be added to **AddRazorPages()**? From what I read controllers just adds CORS and API explorer support. Is this used for something? I tested it by removing AddControllersWithViews and tacking on AddMicrosoftIdentityUI to AddRazorPages and it worked the same.

As there is a default fallback policy of requiring authentication you get redirected to login to an account as soon as the app starts. But looking at the pipeline, no use of **UseAuthentication()** and **UseAuthorization()** middleware is setup. So how is the auth middleware being executed without these being setup? I was under the assumption if this middleware is not setup the app won't handle authentication but that clearly not the case. SignalR docs for authentication state the use of these middleware to enable auth. As SSB uses signalR under the hood, why is this not enabled? For a regular MVC/razor pages application, these middleware ARE used in the default template. So I am wondering why not in this case?

**AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler** - I see this setup for blazor but not for a regular web app. I know this is for consent handling but why is this setup for blazor and not regular MVC app considering blazor server side is server hosted.

The docs don't really state why/how these are not included and how auth middleware is executing, they just explain how authentication is setup. Is something being setup under the hood to force auth to work without the appropriate middleware being included?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Blazor, but I can answer the following question

> But looking at the pipeline, no use of UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() middleware is setup. So how is the auth middleware being executed without these being setup?

Welcome to the magic how-the-hell-it-happened world of the [minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#webapplication):

> - UseAuthentication is added immediately after UseRouting if IAuthenticationSchemeProvider can be detected in the service provider. IAuthenticationSchemeProvider is added by default when using AddAuthentication, and services are detected using IServiceProviderIsService.
> - UseAuthorization is added next if IAuthorizationHandlerProvider can be detected in the service provider. IAuthorizationHandlerProvider is added by default when using AddAuthorization, and services are detected using IServiceProviderIsService.
>   The following code is effectively what the automatic middleware being added to the app produces:

```cs
if (isDevelopment)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseRouting();

if (isAuthenticationConfigured)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
}

if (isAuthorizationConfigured)
{
    app.UseAuthorization();
}

// user middleware/endpoints
app.CustomMiddleware(...);
app.MapGet("/", () => "hello world");
// end user middleware/endpoints

app.UseEndpoints(e => {});
```

Comment: This makes sense, didn't realize minimal API hides some of the actual middleware being applied to the pipeline. Thanks so much for pointing this out